# How to use runas command in windows 2008 r2 server?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a batch file which will call another batch file and delete some files. For this I need to have admin rights. I tried following command...

```
runas /user:bala@nsc cmd
Enter the password for bala@nsc: xxxxxxx
```

Even though bala@nsc has admin rights command prompt is getting opened as a simple user rather than administrator.

I guess, I am missing something. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your results aren't what I expected, either.  But I've got a few workarounds to suggest.

- You could turn off User Account Control.
- You could go to Start --> All Programs --> Accessories, then right-click on "Command Prompt" and choose "Run as Administrator."
- You could right-click on your batch script and do the same.
- You could create a shortcut to either cmd or your batch script on your Desktop, then modify the properties of that shortcut to run as Administrator.
- You could add some code to your batch script to [check for admin privileges and prompt for escalation](https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/home/BatchGotAdmin) if needed.

Turning off UAC would be my choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Link you shared has the logic.